# Changing DIV width with content and placing it at the centre.

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get a div to be centered AND to have a minimum-width of 630px. It should expand in width based on the size of the content.

---

For some reason it is taking up the full width of the page even though I have:

1. centered all content
2. set all divs within it to 600px width
3. have placed test content in it thats not so wide

---

Here are the relevant bits: http://jsfiddle.net/partisanentity/7KGRr/2/

The issue seems to be #imageholder ?

Comment: The div is working as expected. The min-width is 630px and it's conforming to that. The div is showing at the width of the browser which is greater than the min-width, so that's fine. The min-width doesn't mean that the div will set its width to the same value.

Comment: So how would I get the div to expand only with the width of the content and not the way it is expanding now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display:inline-block to your **#content** DIV. Write like this:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}

#content {
    clear:both;
    min-width:630px;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#5b5b5b;
    margin-top:15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7KGRr/3/

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try now.